# Display order custom meta data in Woocommerce Print Invoices & Packing Lists

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In Woocommerce I am using **WooCommerce Print Invoices & Packing Lists** plugin and I am trying to display a custom order meta data value which is a delivery date in an invoice.

This is my code in my theme's functions.php file:

```
function sv_wc_pip_add_order_delivery_shipping( $order_id, $order ) {

    //$order_id = 25775; (this method is working but is static and not dynamic)

    $order_id = $order->get_id();

    $invoice_web_delivery_date = get_post_meta($order_id,'jckwds_date',true);

    echo $invoice_web_delivery_date ;

}

add_filter( 'wc_pip_after_customer_addresses', 'sv_wc_pip_add_order_delivery_shipping', 10, 3 );
```

But the Order_id is not working and not returning the order id for each woocommerce order.

How can I modify this code to get the correct ID for each order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for this hooked function are quite different. Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'wc_pip_after_customer_addresses', 'action_after_customer_addresses', 10, 4 );
function action_after_customer_addresses( $type, $action, $document, $order ) {
    if( $ddate = $order->get_meta( 'jckwds_date' ) )
        echo '<p>'.__("Delivery date") . ': ' . $ddate . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Official documentation for [wc_pip_after_customer_addresses action hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists-developer-reference/#wc_pip_after_customer_addresses):